# Obtaining packet size when reading from QTcpsocket

Tags: qt, sockets

I am developing a server in Qt wherein it will receive packets of fixed size from client. Although packet sizes will remain 
same for specific sequence, they could vary across sequences.

For e.g :-

- Packets received when sequence 1 is selected :-

  pkt1kb, pkt1kb, pkt1kb, pkt1kb .... (all are 1KB in size).
- Packets received when sequence 2 is selected :-

  pkt2kb, pkt2kb, pkt2kb, pkt2kb .... (all are 2KB in size).

Current approach I'm following is :-

- I'm using **QTcpSocket** for receiving data. However, the socket is not receiving complete packet in one go and hence 
  it's hard for me to demarcate two different packets.

Can anyone suggest me as to how to read complete packets so that I could distinguish between two different packets.

**NOTE** :-

- *There are few issues discussed on similar lines previously also. However, my issue is more specific as it I am working
      on fix sized packets.*
- *I have no control over client side.*

Comment: *Note: -* your issue is no different due to using fix sized packets...they can still be broken up before being transmitted across a network and you need to handle that.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: Regardless, a method for determining the packet size on arrival should exist - as opposed to reading the socket as an uninterrupted stream.  (and then you can make informed guesses, using statistic analysis or whatever other desperate methods to try to recover the original packet size.) Making the difference between "works sometimes" vs "doesn't work ever."

Comment: @SF. *a method for determining the packet size on arrival should exist* - which is what the answer demonstrates in the link to the duplicated question.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: `m_pConnection->bytesAvailable()` ? Won't that add up all arriving packets if you're slower at receiving than their arrival frequency?

Comment: @SF. Yes, but you're missing the main point; *...setting the first byte(s) to the number of bytes that will be sent*, which means we tag each message with its size, so inside the loop it first reads the number of bytes to expect for a message.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: And you're missing the main point: the asker has no control over the sender application and its transmission protocol and cannot change what is being sent, thus can't set the first byte to anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142091/discussion-between-thedarkknight-and-sf).